# Having difficulties connecting to Amazon RDS MySql server with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, amazon-rds

I'm just trying a basic connection with a PHP script and running into some issues, my PHP code is simply:

```
$host="endpoint:3306"; // Host name 
$username="user"; // Mysql username 
$password="pw"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="RawData"; // Database name 

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306);

//Check connection
if($conn->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}
```

And getting an error Access denied for user 'user'@'cpe-174-109-76-241.nc.res.rr.com.'  If it is to the point that is is an Access Denied error, is that based on the password?  My password works because I can connect to the instance with MySQL Workbench on this same machine.  Do I need to make an update to my security group for the PHP code to connect through localhost?  Let me know if there is any more information I need to provide, I'm very new to PHP and very lost with this basic setup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a security group preventing access.

Examine the allowable IP addr , adding yours as a test. Consider adding 0.0.0.0 and CIDR in the security group at play with port 3306

http://whatismyipaddress.com if needed

Comment: I added 0.0.0.0 for now and it goes through, thanks!  I'll have to look into why my specific IP is being blocked.